# Возведение двойки в целую степень

Tags: математика, инспекция-кода

Какой код будет быстрее?

```c
res = pow(2, delta);
```

```c
res = 1 << abs(delta);
if (delta < 0)
  res = 1 / res;
```

```c
if (delta >= 0)
  res = 1 << delta;
else
  res = 1 / (1 << -delta);
```

- `delta` - целое
- `res` - double

Comment: У Вас, случаем, не опечатка вот здесь: `res = 1 / delta;`?

Comment: Вы бы уточнили, с какими числами имеем дело. Целые, с плавающей точкой?

Comment: И какой ЯП? Хотя я подозреваю что ни в одном в функции pow нет спецобработки числа 2, так что битовые операции будут быстрее

Comment: Мне кажется, второй код должен быть `res = 1 << abs(delta);
if (delta < 0)
  res = 1.0 / res;`

Comment: @ЮрийКозлов, да, во втором случае ошибка

Comment: @Mikhailo да. Ошибся при написании вопроса

Comment: @Harry так вроде же в заголовке написано, что возводим в целую степень (`int delta`), а `res` очевидно из кода, что float

Comment: @AlexeyTen Вообще Делфи..А как на счет `abs`?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov Об том и спич... И какой тогда сдвиг - он же весь диапазон никак не захватит!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если у вас практический интерес, то можно без всяких там делений - собрать нужное число согласно формату IEEE 754.

Тест на скорую руку показывает времена в мс на 2*10^9 операций (при использовании отрицательной степени):

```
 pow               27000
 1/res             5866
 ieee с ^@         1513 
 ieee с absolute   811
 пустой цикл       760
```

Для `float/single`:

```
var
  s: Single;
  pow: Integer;
  i: Integer;
begin
//  pow := 4;
//  pow := 0;
  pow := -4;
  i := (pow + 127) shl 23;
  s := PSingle(@i)^;
  Memo1.Lines.Add(s.ToString)

 16
 1
 0.0625
```

Для `double` (с использованием `Int64`):

```
i := (pow + 1023) shl 52;
```

Приведение области памяти целого типа к вещественному может быть реализовано любым способом - через указатели, как я сделал, через вариантную запись, через absolute.

Для особо отрицательных степеней (от `2^-126` до `2^-149`) нужно делать денормализованные числа - но есть ли нужда в этом?

Answer (score 1):

Подозреваю, что будет сильно зависеть от языка и, более того, от его конкретной реализации. Вот тест на `Python` в `Google Colab`. И да - в `Python` есть два синтаксических варианта для возведения в степень, и они, как ни странно, различаются по скорости:

```
def test_pow(delta):
    res = pow(2, delta)
    return res

def test_asterisk(delta):
    res = 2 ** delta
    return res

def test_shift(delta):
    res = 1 << abs(delta)
    if delta < 0:
        res = 1 / res
    return res

def test_shift2(delta):
    if delta >= 0:
        res = 1 << delta;
    else:
        res = 1 / (1 << -delta)
    return res

assert test_pow(2) == 4
assert test_pow(-2) == 1/4
assert test_asterisk(2) == 4
assert test_asterisk(-2) == 1/4
assert test_shift(2) == 4
assert test_shift(-2) == 1/4
assert test_shift2(2) == 4
assert test_shift2(-2) == 1/4

%timeit list(map(test_pow, range(-10,10)))
%timeit list(map(test_asterisk, range(-10,10)))
%timeit list(map(test_shift, range(-10,10)))
%timeit list(map(test_shift2, range(-10,10)))
```

Результаты:

```
100000 loops, best of 5: 6.35 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 5: 5.35 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 5: 4.93 µs per loop
100000 loops, best of 5: 3.69 µs per loop
```

Т.е. скорость растёт с каждым вариантом. И можно сделать вывод, что во-первых сдвиги работают быстрее, чем возведение в степень (и это так скорее всего будет в любом языке), а во-вторых (по крайней мере в питоне) вызов любых функций - это накладные расходы, чем меньше вызовов, тем лучше. Я так думаю, выигрыш последнего варианта над предпоследним определяет то, что в нём не вызывается функция `abs`.

Для контроля сделал такой же тест для степеней в диапазоне `[-1000,1000)`, а то вдруг от этого что-то зависит, но суть результатов не поменялась, хотя разрыв между разными вариантами чуть уменьшился:

```
1000 loops, best of 5: 993 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 5: 884 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 5: 790 µs per loop
1000 loops, best of 5: 668 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 1):

Если предположить, что для исходного кода используется язык программирования с генерацией непосредственно исполняемого процессором кода (C/c++), а не скриптовый язык, то для оптимизирущего компилятора два последних случая будут практически эквивалентны и на порядок быстрее первого случая (на x86 платформах с FPU).

В первом способе производятся достаточно тяжеловесные операции по преобразованию целого числа в `double`, а потом ещё и вызов не самой быстрой библиотечной функции.
Слабость же двух последних методов 1) в приведении целого числа к формату с плавающей точкой, 2) в медленной операции деления, 3) в ветвлении в зависимости от знака `delta`

Если же использовать способ от @MBo (при твёрдой уверенности, что double на платформе соответсвует формату binary64 IEEE 754, а значение `delta` находится в нужном диапазоне)

> ...без всяких там делений - собрать нужное число согласно формату IEEE 754.

, то это будет быстрый, хоть и не столь "законный" способ выполнить

```cpp
    res = ldexp(1.0, delta);
```

, но без реального вызова самой библиотечной функции, выполнения проверок в ней, формирования аргументов для неё.

Достаточно "просто" написать нечто

```cpp
    res = reinterpret_cast<double&&>(
        reinterpret_cast<int64_t&&>(1.0) +
        (static_cast<int64_t>(delta) << std::numeric_limits<double>::digits -
                                            /* hidden bit */ 1));
```

Здесь для формирования результата инструкции и ресурсы FPU вообще не используется, все операции целочисленные. Результат формируется сдвигом и сложением с константой.

Если описать используемые переменные

```cpp
int const volatile delta = -7;
double volatile res;
```

, а тело "пустого цикла"

```cpp
    (void)delta;
```

, чтобы оптимизирующий компилятор всё же делал обращения к аргументам, а не свёл цикл к единственной операции, то характерные времена на одну итерацию

| Способ | Время итерации (ns) |
| --- | --- |
| "пустой цикл" | 0.3525 |
| способ №1 (с pow) | 26.7643 |
| способ №2 (с abs) | 2.4101 |
| способ №3 (с ветвлением по знаку) | 2.4372 |
| способ @MBo бинарной сборки числа в формате IEEE 754 | 0.4051 |
| ldexp | 9.0168 |

Отсюда видно, что способы №2 и №3 в десяток раз быстрее, чем первый, но и способ @MBo значительно быстрее, чем любой из исходной задачи.

Указанные времена похожи на времена, измеренные @MBo, если откалибровать время доступа к исходным данным.

Из этой же таблицы видны и отличия от измерений в интерпретаторе, где оправдываются подозрения @CrazyElf в том, что

> разрыв между разными вариантами...
>
> ...будет сильно зависеть от языка и, более того, от его конкретной реализации

, а вовсе не от низкоуровневых операций.

Дополнительное замечание об ограничениях указанных способов:

1. `pow` и `ldexp` обрабатывают выход за диапазоны двоичной экспоненты штатным образом.
2. Способ @MBo требует контроля диапазона в пределах 11 битного представления `delta`.
3. Диапазон же допустимых значений `delta` для способов №2 и №3 совсем узкий: не более 6 бит.